# Nested Datasets com FdQuery Firedac

Tags: delphi, firedac

Olá pessoal tudo certo? Preciso tirar uma dúvida, quando utilizava dbExpress, era possível fazer mestre detalhe com o clientDataSet usando o Nested DataSet, onde no clientDataSet PAI, abria uma nova coluna DataSet (com os dados da tabela filha) e assim eu utilizava para consultar e aplicar os dados no banco.

Porém, ao utilizar o Firedac com FdQuery, não consegui achar uma forma de fazer isso, a única forma que consegui algo semelhante é utilizar o fdSchemaAdapter e fazer o relacionamento entre os fdquerys através dos DataSources.

Alguém sabe me informar se esta opção é suportada pelo firedac?

**Eu não entendi como montar o SQL da tabela pai "SELECT * FROM {id Orders}" e como relacionado com o SQL da tabela Filha "SELECT * FROM {id Order Details}"**

Fonte: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Master-Detail_Relationship_(M/D)